# How to merge from trunk to branch ignoring all private changes

Tags: svn-merge

Trunk svn url: `http://svn.myserver.com/trunk/project1`

Private branch created from above branch: `http://svn.myserver.com/trunk/project1_myprivate`

Now after some merging from trunk to private and private to trunk, finally I want to merge from trunk to myprivate branch but this time want to accept all changes of trunk and ignoring myprivate, what commands I need to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `svn revert` at first.

See more here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html

Comment: I know this was two years ago, but I don't think he meant "ignoring local changes" I think he meant "ignoring changes committed to the private branch", which is a much trickier question.